# Keep getting 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'show' error on DataBricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to do a few simple things in the notebook such as just viewing the data and change data types of some of the columns in this data frame but I keep getting an error that states `'DataFrame' object has no attribute` along with whatever command I'm trying to run.

I'm trying to work with a local csv stored on DBFS .

Here is what my data types and dataframe looks like, along with a sample of the data itself:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are aware of the fact that it is a pandas dataframe and not a Spark dataframe?

Comment: On databricks you can use `display`: `display(df)` works both if `df` is a `pandas` dataframe or a `spark` dataframe.

Comment: @RobertKossendey Yeah, I'm brand new to PySpark so apologies for dumb, super simple questions. I'd like to plot some frequency bar charts and histograms for distribution on some of those variables listed. I was also trying to change datatypes of the variables since all of them are showing as "object" instead of int, string, etc.

Comment: But that definitely seems to be my issue. I wasn't using Pandas commands, so thank you @PieCot and Robert.

Comment: Don't worry, happy that we were able to help :)